# call onMapReady manualy in Google Map Api ver2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm using Google Map Api ver 2 in Android app. I have implemented drawing marker in call onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) and it works fine.

After changing marker cooridnates in the same fragment I would like manually to initialize onMapReady(). Any have idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Move the "drawing marker" code into a separate method.

Step #2: Call that method from `onMapReady()`.

Step #3: Call that method "after changing marker coordinates in the same fragment".

Comment: Is it possible to use it without fragment? I am using it inside Activity.Can i call onMapReady manually?

Comment: @JayDangar: "Is it possible to use it without fragment?" -- you do not need to use `MapFragment`, if that is what you mean. There is [a separate `MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) that you can use directly, though it is more work. "Can i call onMapReady manually?" -- no. After all, you have no idea when the map is ready. You call `getMapAsync()` on the `MapView`, and your `OnMapReadyCallback` will be called with `onMapReady()` when the map is ready.